# WordPress plugin notifications

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin for my clients that advises me when Core, Plugin, or Theme updates are available and emails this to me.  I would like to change the default update notification text when this plugin is activated to something like "Plugin update is available however, updates are managed by company xyz".

// Disable core updates

```
    # 2.3 to 2.7:
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

    # 2.8 to 3.0:
    remove_action( 'wp_version_check', 'wp_version_check' );
    remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_core' );
    add_filter( 'pre_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

    # 3.0:
    add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );    

// Disable plugin updates

    # 2.3 to 2.7:
    add_action( 'admin_menu', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'load-plugins.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );") );
        # Why use the admin_menu hook? It's the only one available between the above hook being added and being applied
    add_action( 'admin_init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_update_plugins' );"), 2 );
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_update_plugins' );"), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_plugins', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

    # 2.8 to 3.0:
    remove_action( 'load-plugins.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
    remove_action( 'load-update.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
    remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_plugins' );
    remove_action( 'wp_update_plugins', 'wp_update_plugins' );
    add_filter( 'pre_transient_update_plugins', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

    # 3.0:
    remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
    add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

Comment: I found the following code, but the issue is I don't want to disable the notifications, I want to change the wording.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't really an answer to the question, but the above code is unfortunately all over the net and it's badly incorrect.  While returning null to the pre_site_ filters *does* suppress the notification messages, it also forces wordpress to check for updates continuously, because it can't tell when the last update check was made.

The code below (5.3+) implements a better version that suppresses the messages without making WP run update checks on every single WP admin request.

```
$func = function ($a) {
    global $wp_version;
    return (object) array(
        'last_checked' => time(),
        'version_checked' => $wp_version,
    );
};
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', $func);
```